# HandleError partial view redirect to action change only the partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have main view that contain partial view.
I have HandleError that by chance of error I redirect to other action that return other view .
the problem is that when I have error in the partial view only the partial view has changed.
what can I do?
the controller:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext != null)
    {
        Exception e = filterContext.Exception;
        Log.Error(e);
    }
    RedirectToAction("Login", "Start", new { authorityId = 1, TopUnit = "RRRRR", unitId = 1, SubUnitId = 1 });
}
```

I need that all the view will change, the partial and the main.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you see a partial view instead of whole view when you get error in partial view?

Comment: I mean that in error i want that all the view will change and only the partial view changed

Answer (score 0):

As you said on error partial view only changed, you could try below work around:

**OnException Redirect to intermediate action**

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext != null)
    {
        Exception e = filterContext.Exception;
        Log.Error(e);
    }

    RedirectToAction("RedirectOnError", "Start", new { authorityId = 1, TopUnit = "RRRRR", unitId = 1, SubUnitId = 1 });
}
```

**Create Partial View _RedirectToError.cshtml with below code in Login Folder**

```
 <script>
   window.location = '@Url.Action("Login", "Start",new { authorityId = 1, TopUnit = "RRRRR", unitId = 1, SubUnitId = 1 })';
</script>
```

**In Start Controller**

```
public ActionResult RedirectOnError(){
   return PartialView("_RedirectToError");
}
```

Once RedirectOnError executes you will get redirected to Login with a full view.